# Build 2d pyramidal array - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've been boggling my head to make this array for some time but having no success doing it in a vectorized way.

I need a function that takes in the 2d array size n and produces a 2d array of size (n, n) looking like this:

```
n = 6

np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,1,1,1,1,0],
          [0,1,2,2,1,0],
          [0,1,2,2,1,0],
          [0,1,1,1,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
```

(and can take odd number arguments)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What was the non-vectorized way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def pyramid(n):
    r = np.arange(n)
    d = np.minimum(r,r[::-1])
    return np.minimum.outer(d,d)
```

**Approach #2**

We can also use `concatenation` to create `d`, like so -

```
d = np.r_[np.arange(n//2),np.arange(n//2-(n%2==0),-1,-1)]
```

Thus, giving us an alternative one-liner -

```
np.minimum.outer(*(2*[np.r_[np.arange(n//2),np.arange(n//2-(n%2==0),-1,-1)]]))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [83]: pyramid(5)
Out[83]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [84]: pyramid(6)
Out[84]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [85]: pyramid(8)
Out[85]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Nice use of `np.minimum.outer` here, this is a pretty neat solution

Comment: My God this is so smart.

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.pad`:

```
import numpy as np

def pyramid(n):
    if n % 2:
        arr = np.zeros((1,1))
        N = int((n-1)/2)
    else:
        arr = np.zeros((2,2))
        N = int(n/2)-1

    for i in range(N):
        arr += 1
        arr = np.pad(arr, 1, mode='constant')
    return arr
```

Output:

```
pyramid(6)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

pyramid(5)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

`numpy.pad(arr, 1, 'constant')` returns `arr` wrapped with 1 layer of zeros.

Comment: Although I like the approach, it looks pretty inefficient from both a time perspective (`np.pad` has to create a new array, with the memory allocation and the inherent time overhead), and with regards to the memory, as I foresee that `arr = np.pad(arr)` will cause `arr` and its padded copy to coexist at one instant, leading to RAM peaks. I think that creating an array with the right shape beforehand and then filling it would be much more efficient. +1 though for the approach, somewhat functional-esque